# Dispatching /Mapping URLS in python without using Flask

Tags: python, url-mapping

Back ground:
I bought a web hosting plan and created (by WordPress) a website.  Now I want to create a new website on that server by python/flask but not WordPress because the standardized functions do not meet my requirements.

Problem description:
For testing purpose, I did not edit any Conf files or WSGI settings, just executed "python init.py" to start the new python web applications, in the backend, it showed app is running at http://:localhost:5000. But in the frontend, the web browser ended up waiting for response.
My web hosting provider had a look and they said Flask is not allowed for some security reasons.

My question:
I need to bind URLs to proper pages without using flask framework.  Any suggestions and recommendations are welcome. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] your question and add how you're deploying the app? Is it a `Dockerfile` image or `docker-compose`? Also the `gunicorn` configuration file. Anyway, there is no need to run Flask as `root` so something is wrong with the deployment process.

Comment: Hello lepsh,  Thanks very much for your help.  I have edited my questions.
For example:
On my test Server, Flask is used to control url mapping.
@app.route("/hello/")
def hello():
    return render_template("hello.html") 

But Falsk is not allowed for security reasons on some severs, how to bind the url "/hello/" with the function def hello():?

Comment: On the server side you should bind the special IP address `0.0.0.0` and port `80` for `http` access.  But it depends on which web-hosting you have. They probably have an Nginx to route `https` to the `http` server on some port. You should check chich port is that.

Comment: They have a default homepage on port 80.  Yes, there are lot of things to be checked  with web-hosting provider. Thanks very much for your coaching.